# how to extract column data given a row value in R dynamically without row/column reference

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in below format

```
X.0   X.1     X.2       X.3      X.4     X.5    X.6     X.7     X.8
      Oct-18                            
      A12018  A22018    A32018   A42018  A12019 A22019  A32019  A42019
      XXX     XXX       XXX      YYY     YYY    YYY     YYY     YYY
ABC   32.5    30.9      28.3     29.3    30     31.5    32      32
PQR   667     677       722      740     730    705     710     710
ABC   799     784       739      730     735    740     750     750
```

Here x.0, x.1 are the columns.

> I need to extract Column values, under Oct-18 and  from A12019 to
>   A42019 for the value ABC

Comment: Which one is the column name?

Comment: column names are X.0, X.1 etc

Comment: So, 'Oct_18' is an element under 'X.1'?

Comment: yes, and under that you have A12018, A22018 etc.

Comment: If it is the second column to last one, then do `df[df$X.0 == "ABC", 2:9]`

Comment: Smthg like this `df[which(df$X1 == "ABC"), which(df[3,] == "A12019"):which(df[3,] == "A42019")]` ?

Comment: I have to dynamically retrieve without any column or row reference/name

Answer (score 0):

We can extract a row providing the column index and row index

```
df[df$X.0 == "ABC", 2:9]
```